# latex symbols to indicate telephone and mobile on letterhead

Tags: symbols

I want to add symbols for telephone and mobile on article class rather than writing Phone no: 0999999999 and mobile number 099999999999999. Are there any available symbols to indicate telephone and mobile handset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
\phone 
\end{document}
```